# Problem writing a simple SELECT query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES ('"+UsersIdentityToinsert+"')"; //Exception: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Reputation', table 'model.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

The statement has been terminated.

When i execute this command with sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();. it says i cant put nulls in to the column. But in the debugging, i saw that UsersIdentityToinsert has a Guid value

Comment: 1. This doesn't make sense, you prose doesn't match the code. Post a complete re-create of your problem (but no excess beyond that). 2. Don't use string concatenation to build SQL it will lead to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Did you initialize `checkExistingUserID`?

Comment: well, no, i just fed some values inside

Comment: Stop editing the title every time.

Comment: Indeed... That is getting rather annoying.

Comment: lol..i am trying to debug the insert statement now. it throws an exception saying that i cant put null inside. i edited my quesion

Comment: okay, it worked. i modified all my insert and select statements it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is reader null?

It shouldn't be. It may have .HasRows == false, but there should be an object.

Why do you think it ever is null?

---

OK, new title with a clue.

You have to drop the `@` in the SQL text as it denotes @UserID as a parameter and not as a column. And I'm also doubtful about the SELECT part. Try:

```
"SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID= '" + UsersIDentity + "'"
```

Comment: i removed the try{} and i saw a new exception : see above

Comment: now i get this ..in the same spot : Incorrect syntax near 'fd6d35d'.

Comment: Probably you need quotes around the value... edited.

Comment: I have mistakes all over the statement..what does u represent? name of the column/field?

Comment: Try your queries in Mgmt Studio or Visual studio first. I'll edit again.

Comment: is there a way to prevent sql injection?..cause, i was told that is not a secure wayto write code